# assign separate middleware to each method of a resource in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, entrust

I am using [Zizaco/entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/) laravel package as a ACL Manager for my project.

I know that for limit access to a route group via middlewares and assign a role (or permission) to it, I should do that like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['role:admin']], function() {
    ....
});
```

But I want to assign separate permission to different routes(methods) of a resource controller.

I know that how can so that for whole resource but I can not implement it for each controller method:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['role:admin']], function() {
        Route::resource('/post', ['middleware' => ['permission:manage-posts'], 'uses' => 'PostController']);

    });
```

I want to assing this permission to related method :

```
'post-create' => public function create ()  
'post-edit' => public function edit()
```

and so on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can assign middlewares in your controller's constructor:

```
class Foo extends Conroller
{
    public function __construct() {

        $this->middleware('post-create', ['only' => ['create']]);

        $this->middleware('post-edit', ['only' => ['edit']]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have many models and each have individual resources that those have different methods.
do I add middleware for each methods ?
are not there another simple and general solution ?

Comment: @A.B.Developer Middlewares like any other classes should have a single responsibility, you could write some complicated conditional code to make a middleware usable for more than one method but then it will become harder to maintain and expand.

Comment: does not seem to be a good answer. this method will need to use one middleware for each methods. Will be too much for the developer

Comment: @ZahanSafallwa That is what the OP wanted - please read the quesiton: `assign separate middleware to each method of a resource in laravel`

Comment: @AngadDubey cant we use single middleware file and just use parameter to place different permission? i think that would be much efficient. otherwise creating a middleware file for each and every method is kinda overhead i guess

Comment: @ZahanSafallwa you can - but that is not what OP is looking for - OP explicitly wants them to be separate, please read the question ( `But I want to assign separate permission to different routes(methods) of a resource controller`

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have **apiResource** *units-of-measure*. You can assign different middlewares to separate endpoints like this:

```
Route::middleware('role:seller|buyer')->group(function () {
    Route::apiResource('units-of-measure', UnitOfMeasureController::class)->only('index');
});

Route::middleware('role:seller')->group(function () {
    Route::apiResource('units-of-measure', UnitOfMeasureController::class)->except('index');
});
```

The **index** endpoint will be accessible for sellers as well as for buyers. The rest of endpoints are only for sellers.

Answer (score -1):

you can chain the methods, using the `only` method.
here is an example:

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\Models\User;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
    use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
    
    class UserController extends Controller
    {
    
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('permission:read-user')->only('index','show');
            $this->middleware('permission:edit-user')->only('edit','update');
            $this->middleware('permission:delete-user')->only('delete');
            $this->middleware('permission:create-user')->only('create','store');
        }
```